# Sending object using ajax to Model

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

i have an Ajax code that handles a booking form the javascript is creating a json object that get consumed and adds the data to the C# Model and in the ConstructBookEmailMessage it creates the email body by getting the data from the model that will be filled by the json that was created by the javascript code it should be very simple but the model is alwayes null the json object is correctly fill with data but not sending the data to the model so the name is null no matter what i try

```
SendBookEmail: function (a, e) {
    $("#btnsendbook").click(function (s) {
        if ($(".successmessage").css("display", "none"), s.preventDefault(), !$(".bookmailform").valid()) return !1;

        var n = $("#name").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "api/Form/SendBookEmail",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                Name: n
            },
            success: function (response) {
                if (response) {
                    DRHossam.ClearControls();
                    $("#loader").hide();
                    $("#success").slideDown("slow");
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $("#success").slideUp("slow");
                    }, 4000);
                } else {
                    DRHossam.ClearControls();
                    $("#loader").hide();
                    $("#error").slideDown("slow");
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $("#error").slideUp("slow");
                    }, 4000);
                }
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log("Error in AJAX request:", error);
            },
        });
    });
},
```

and this is the contoller

```
[AcceptVerbs("POST", "PUT", "GET")]
[ActionName("SendBookEmail")]
public bool SendBookEmail([FromBody] DrHossamElMahdy.UI.Models.BookFormEntity Email)
{
    #region SendEmail
    try
    {

        DrHossamElMahdy.Core.Repositories.SqlServer_Repositories.SQLServerTestimonialsRepository TestimonialRepository = new Core.Repositories.SqlServer_Repositories.SQLServerTestimonialsRepository();
        DrHossamElMahdy.UI.UIHelper Helper = new UIHelper();
        string Message = ConstructBookEmailMessage(Email);
        bool sent = Helper.SendMail(Email.Name, "BookNow", Message);
        

        if (sent)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Exception in SendBookEmail: {ex.Message}");

        return false;
    }
    return false;
    #endregion
}
```

```
private string ConstructBookEmailMessage(BookFormEntity Email)
{
    string EmailMessage = "";
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Email.Name))
    {
        EmailMessage = "<b>Name:</b>" + Email.Name + "<br>";
    }
    //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Email.Email))
    //{
    //    EmailMessage += "<b>Email:</b>" + Email.Email + "<br>";
    //}
    //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Email.Phone))
    //{
    //    EmailMessage += "<b>Phone:</b>" + Email.Phone + "<br>";
    //}

    //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Email.Date))
    //{
    //    EmailMessage += "<b>Date:</b>" + Email.Date + "<br>";
    //}
    //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Email.Weight))
    //{
    //    EmailMessage += "<b>Weight:</b>" + Email.Weight + "<br>";
    //}
    //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Email.Height))
    //{
    //    EmailMessage += "<b>Length:</b>" + Email.Height + "<br>";
    //}
    //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Email.Type))
    //{
    //    EmailMessage += "<b>Message Type:</b>" + Email.Type + "<br>";
    //}
    return EmailMessage;
}
```

and this the model

````
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace DrHossamElMahdy.UI.Models
{
    public class BookFormEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        //public string Email { get; set; }
        //public string Phone { get; set; }
        //public string Date { get; set; }
        //public string Weight { get; set; }
        //public string Height { get; set; }
        //public int LanguageID { get; set; }
        //public string Type { get; set; }
        //public string Clinic { get; set; }
    }
}```
it always comes with null although i am sure that the front is filling the object correct 
but Email.Name comes with null
````

Comment: You need to send (BookFormEntity Email) in the ajax body in JSON format
contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
data: JSON.stringify({'Email': emailObject}),